# JOOQ:The method and(Boolean) from the type Condition is deprecated

Tags: java, jooq

While using JOOQ, dsl.select() with .and() I got "The method and(Boolean) from the type Condition is deprecated" such kind of warning. Iam using jooq 3.8.3.
Does anybody can brief me about this?

Comment: Maybe you can find an answer on [this](https://www.jooq.org/notes) page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it, I was using equals method instead of equal,like

```
.where(AePlan.AE_PLAN.PLAN_ID**.equals**(planId)
.and(AePlan.AE_PLAN.PHARMACYNETWORK_ID.**equals**(pharmacyNW_Id))
```

Use of equal is worked for me!!

Answer (score 1):

That method (and many other similar methods) were deprecated in jOOQ 3.8 with issue [#4763](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4763), precisely for the reason you've experienced and [documented yourself in your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42432047/521799).

Many people accidentally used the [`Object.equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) method rather than the [`Field.equal()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html#equal-org.jooq.Field-) method (e.g. because of accidental IDE auto completion), believing that they are producing a valid jOOQ [`Condition`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Condition.html), when they were really producing a `boolean` constant.

If there wasn't any [`Condition.and(Boolean)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Condition.html#and-java.lang.Boolean-) "convenience methods", you would have simply gotten a compilation error and fixed your mistake. But with the `Condition.and(Boolean)` method, your code compiles and runs fine, but your query doesn't do what you intentioned.

Thus the "convenience method" that produced this confusing results was deprecated again.

On a side-note, you can avoid this problem by using the two-letter abbreviated forms like [`Field.eq()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html#eq-org.jooq.Field-) instead.

Comment: Hey thanks Lukas...really appreciate for your response!!! And yes it is just because of auto correction of IDE.